# Getting table heading to "wrap" onto another line

Tags: tables, multirow

I have the following

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array,multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\caption{\label{tbl:table_label}Table description}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lccccc}
\hline \hline
{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Lattice Parameter} & Layer Separation \\
\cmidrule{2-4} 
Type of work & a ({\AA}) & b ({\AA}) & c ({\AA}) & ({\AA}) & Ref.  \\
\hline
\rule{2pt}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{12pt}This & a & b & c & \# & $^{a}$  \\
\rule{2pt}{0pt}That & a & b & c & \# & $^{a}$  \\
\rule{2pt}{0pt}And & a & b & c & \# & $^{a}$  \\
\rule{2pt}{0pt}The & a & b & c & \# & $^{a}$  \\
\rule{2pt}{0pt}Other & a & b & c & \# & $^{a}$  \\
\hline \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

My problem is that I would like to get the word "Separation" beneath "Layer" without adding to the overall height of the headers as they currently sit. I have tried using `\multirow` or defining a `\newcolumntype`, but to no avail. Thank you in advance from a LaTeX novice.

Comment: Beware that the space below “Layer Separation” seems big, but if you remove the `review` option it won't be as big and won't allow for an additional line. The final printout will not have so generous vertical spacing.

Answer (score 3):

The vertical space *seems* very large, but it's an effect of the `review` option.

Apart from the font, the ultimate printout would be

[image]

and, quite likely, the copy editors would remove the redefinition of `\arraystretch` to 1.2, leading to

[image]

Here's a possible way out: note that I removed the `review` option in order to be sure the header fits in the ultimate printout.

```
\documentclass[
  %review
]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\small
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}}lccccc}
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Lattice Parameter}
  & \smash{% the vertical extent will not be seen
      \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}Layer \\ Separation\end{tabular}%
    } \\
\addlinespace[2.5pt]
\cmidrule{2-4} 
\addlinespace[2.5pt]
Type of work & a ({\AA}) & b ({\AA}) & c ({\AA}) & (\AA) & Ref.  \\
\midrule
This & a & b & c & \# & $^{a}$  \\
That & a & b & c & \# & $^{a}$  \\
And & a & b & c & \# & $^{a}$  \\
The & a & b & c & \# & $^{a}$  \\
Other & a & b & c & \# & $^{a}$  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{\label{tbl:table_label}Table description}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

According to the parameters set in `elsarticle` it's likely that they want table captions below the table.

Answer (score 3):

A solution using the `\Shortunderstack` command from `stackengine:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Table caption}
  \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{5}{c}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Lattice Parameter} &%\cellset{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}}
     \setstackgap{S}{0pt}\smash[b]{\Shortunderstack {Layer\\Separation\\(\AA)}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    Type of work & a (\AA) & b (\AA) & c (\AA) & & Ref. \\
    \midrule
    This & a & b & c & \# & $^{a}$ \\
    That & a & b & c & \# & $^{a}$ \\
    And & a & b & c & \# & $^{a}$ \\
    The & a & b & c & \# & $^{a}$ \\
    Other & a & b & c & \# & $^{a}$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without using any additional packages, set that particular heading item inside its own `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Table caption}
  \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{5}{c}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Lattice Parameter} & 
      \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}} Layer \\ Separation \end{tabular} \\
    \cmidrule{2-4} 
    Type of work & a (\AA) & b (\AA) & c (\AA) & (\AA) &  Ref.   \\
    \midrule
    This         &    a    &    b    &    c    &   \#  & $^{a}$  \\
    That         &    a    &    b    &    c    &   \#  & $^{a}$  \\
    And          &    a    &    b    &    c    &   \#  & $^{a}$  \\
    The          &    a    &    b    &    c    &   \#  & $^{a}$  \\
    Other        &    a    &    b    &    c    &   \#  & $^{a}$  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem with your answer is the extra space now created above "Lattice Parameter"

Answer (score 2):

You may like to write content of `\multicolumn` cell in two lines:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{Table caption}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{5}c}
    \toprule
                & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\makecell[b]{Lattice\\ Parameters}}
                                                &   \makecell[b]{Layer\\ Separation}                                
                                                        &       \\
    \cmidrule {2-4}
Type of work    & a (\AA) & b (\AA) & c (\AA)   & (\AA) &  Ref.  \\
    \midrule
Longer type name
                &    a    &    b    &    c      &   \#  & $^{a}$ \\
That            &    a    &    b    &    c      &   \#  & $^{a}$ \\
And             &    a    &    b    &    c      &   \#  & $^{a}$ \\
The             &    a    &    b    &    c      &   \#  & $^{a}$ \\
Other           &    a    &    b    &    c      &   \#  & $^{a}$ \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]